# jQuery animate to top of the viewport

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm creating a product page for an e-commerce website which has a fixed bar at the top of the page and the basket within that. There are lots of items on the page and hence there are lots of 'Add To Basket' buttons.

I need the Add To Basket button to fly up to the basket at the fixed bar. At the moment, I've managed to get the box to appear where I need it to appear when clicked, however there isn't any transition with the animation. I'm guessing it could be the fact that I'm turning the object into a `position:fixed;`.

Here's a fiddle of what I've got so far.. Hope you can help!

http://jsfiddle.net/d7tHU/

```
$('.addToCart').click(function(){
    $(this).css('position','fixed');
    $(this).animate({
        top: '0px',
        right:'0px'
    }, "slow");

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a working version for you here http://jsfiddle.net/ZET98/

What I did was changed the positions from `margin-top` and `margin-left` to `top` and `right`

I also changed your javascript to animate the when the parent is clicked and update the `top` css value

```
$( ".addToCart").parent()
.click(function() {
  $(this)
  .css({
      position:'fixed',
      top: $(this).offset().top - $(window).scrollTop()+'px'
  })
  .animate({
    right: $(this).children('.addToCart').outerWidth()+'px',
    top:"0",
  });
});
```

Comment: I struggled with implementing this to work with my page as the positioning of the buttons was different to how I done it in my jsFiddle. But nonetheless, I got there in the end with your help. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry for the trouble implementing, but I'm glad you were able to get it to work!

Answer (score 4):

A CSS solution that uses the `transition` attribute and has less reliance on JavaScript: http://jsfiddle.net/d7tHU/10/

Answer (score 1):

I guess what you want is this 'http://jsfiddle.net/d7tHU/11/'.

```
$('.addToCart').click(function(){
    $(this).css('position','absolute');
    $(this).animate({
        top: -$(this).offset().top+'px',
        left: ($('#basket').offset().left - $('#basket').width()) +'px'
    }, "slow", function(){
        $(this).hide().appendTo('#basket')
           .css({position:'static', float:'right'})
           .fadeIn()
           .off('click');
        $('.price').html(parseFloat($('.price').html())+12.5);
    });    
});
```

The HTML little mod:

```
<div id='header'>
    <div id='basket'>
        <span style="padding-right:10px">Price: <span class="price">0</span>€</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It has a problem, still, to keep them at the top. I'm working on a fiddle to fix that.

Comment: That's nearly what I want, but the problem with your code is that if I scrolled down and then clicked on a button, it doesn't end up in the correct position!

Comment: Yes, i'm fixing it for your.

Comment: I updated the code, now it even updates an hypothetical price field, and the "products" are added to the basket element... makes more sense.

Answer (score 1):

I think this might send you in the right direction.

http://jsfiddle.net/y7W4N/12/

You are targeting the inner div, target the parent as that is what you want to move
ie `$( ".addToCart").parent()`,

Also your script is changing position, ie left, but you have margin-left... so just work on top left etc.

EDIT
a better version http://jsfiddle.net/b5Uux/ <-wrong link this is better

http://jsfiddle.net/b5Uux/1/

Comment: you can animate `right` to `$(this).children('.addToCart').outerWidth()+'px'`. that will make it hug the edge of `#basket`

Comment: Thanks for that, included something similar.